# Woocommerce change "proceed to cart" button with "add to cart" button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce after pressing on “add to cart” button on some product (shop page) it changes its state to “proceed to cart”. It is necessary to change this button behaviour to allow user to add to cart the product one more time (without need to refresh the page or go to cart page). It means that after pressing “add to cart” button once or several times the button should not change it state to allow user to add the product to cart so many times as it needed. How to do it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: User can always increase/decrease the product quantity in cart page.

Comment: Yes, thats right. But the question is about button behaviour on shop page.

Comment: It is possibly your theme, because I don't think that is default behavior.